# Number of expected edges in a simple undirected graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, expected-value

I am new to stack exchange and to discrete mathematics, so please correct me if anything is wrong.
In my homework one questions ask me to find the expected edges in a **simple undirected graph** with **N labelled** vertices.
The question also requires me to find the answer
(a) By directly using the definition of expectation.
(b) By using the linearity of expectation.

I approach this question as follows:
(a) Let X be a random variable that denotes the number of edges in a graph, then
$$E(X) = \frac{1}{2^{\frac {n(n-1)}{2}}}\sum_{i = 1}^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}} i \times \binom{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}{i}$$  since there are $\frac{n(n-1)} {2}$  edges possible in a complete n graph, and for each edge it can be in the graph or not, so there are $2^\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ possible graphs. Then there are $\binom {\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}{i}$ graphs with i edges because we can choose i of the all possible edges for such a graph.
I computed this value to be $$\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

(b) Let X be a random variable that denotes the number of edges in a graph, so $$X = \sum_{i=1}^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}x_{i}$$ where $x_{i} = 1$ if this edge is present in the graph and $x_{i} = 0$ otherwise.  Then
$$ E(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}E(x_{i})$$ by the linearity of expectation, I found each $E(x_{i})$ to be $\frac{1}{2}$ becasue an edge can either present in the graph or not. But this summation evaluates to 
$$\frac{n^{2}(n+1)(n-1)}{8}$$  which does not equal the answer from part(a).

I don't know where I did wrong for this problem, can anyone help me please? Thank you very much!

Comment: In part b) you should get ${n(n-1)\over4}$   Each term in the sum is $\frac12$ and there are  ${n(n-1)\over2}$ terms.  The answer in part a) is incorrect.  It can't be the case that, on average, every edge is in the graph.  The sum looks right to me, so  think you made a mistake in simplifying it.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out my cauculation error in part (b), but I don't understand the part when you suggest "It can't be the case that, on average, every edge is in the graph", can you please clarify this?

Comment: The number of edges in the graph is ${n(n-1)\over2}$  This is the value you got for the average in part a).  The only way that could happen is if every random graph comprised all the edges, which is obviously not true.